# IDEs version compatibility with ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am not able to find which IDEs are compatible with Asp.NET Core.
I want to develop an app and I don´t know which are the possibilities.

Someone can list the compatible IDEs versions? Or some place where they are listed?

I am specially interested in Visual Studio versions

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to work on the *current* version of Visual Studio?

Comment: which version? Thats the question

Comment: Use the *current*. That's 2017. In any case ASP.NET Core is under constant development, now in 2.0 with 2.1 coming out this semester. The tooling changes all the time. The best support is always provided by the current VS version with VS 2015 getting limited support if any

Comment: you know some place where I can check since which version VS is compatible?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2017. The Community edition is fully functional and free: [Visual Studio 2017 Community Download](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/)

Visual Studio Code will also work and is cross platform. You can download it from here: [VS Code Download](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

JetBrain's Rider will also work with ASP.NET Core: [JetBrain's Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/), though it is not free.

Here's where MS tells you how to get started and what IDE you should use. Notice that the link to D/L the IDE takes you to a download of VS 2017 Community. This is the closest thing to an official "here's what's supported" you're going to get. [.NET Core Getting Started.](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows)

Comment: Where is written that VS 2017 is the only VS Version comaptible with .NET Core?

Comment: @Badulake what is the *real* question here? Why do you insist on getting something that says you can work with 2 year old versions, that *don't* get tooling updates? Is this a licesning question? An upgrade question?

Comment: Because my company has only license for VS 2013 and i need to show something official

Comment: @Badulake then you aren't supported and that's it. You have to upgrade anyway. You can't *buy* VS 2015 anymore, so you'll have to move to 2017

Comment: that is like saying, earth is rounded because it is. I need some place with criterya to prove that.

Comment: @Badulake SO is a Q&A site about *programming* not licensing. Did you try searching Microsoft's and ASP.NET Core's web sites? *That's* where you'll find the information you want

Comment: You now have a list of known IDEs that work with ASP.NET Core. Three to be specific. There may be others, but older versions of Visual Studio are not it.

Comment: I googled and surfed for a while, but they are not clear since which version they support it

Comment: @SteveBrouillard add some official link and i will mark it as answer

Comment: @Badulake: .NET Core relies heavily on the Rosyln compiler, which was only introduced in VS 2015. This is hard functional limitation that nothing can be done about. .NET Core is not support in previous versions of VS and never will be. Even then, VS 2015 isn't totally feature-complete in this regard, so it only supports .NET Core 1.1. To use .NET Core 2.0, *you must use 2017*. There is no other option. Like Steve said, the Community edition is free, or you can use VS Code.

Comment: @ChrisPratt. Thanks for the reminder of the reliance on Roslyn. Good point. I was trying to keep my answer concise, so I shied away from the 1.1 support in 2015 to avoid muddying the waters, but also an excellent point.